# Auto posting in facebook on behalf of a user from an application using php

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

**for the below question i asked recently i got a solution here : http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/**

**Its working in core php.
I am new to codeigniter and i am using it in codeigniter.
but this code is not working in codeigniter. I guess the problem was in giving the path in "site url" of the app i created.
I do not know how to give the path of a codeigniter view page in "site url".
Also i need to split this code as: fb Login in one view page and sharing in another view page. Please helpme solve it using codeigniter.**

I am a student with no experience. 
I wanted to autopost on a users facebook account from my application in clicking a single button, using PHP in codeigniter framework.
My requirement is that :There will be many users in my system, and when a user logs into the application and click on a facebook button, the corresponding content should be shared on his facebook account wall.When another user logs in the same should happen and content should be shared on that corresponding users fb wall.

Please help

Comment: When the user uses Facebook Login in your app your app will get a user access token. That token you then use to do requests to Facebook

Comment: ok I get what you said. Thats what i do not know to do. Get the user access token for every user registered in my application. The code part

Comment: It is described in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: Ok thankyou,I will go through it . In case of any doubt hope i can get back to you.

Comment: you must read the platform policy too. autoposting and prefilling the message parameter is not allowed.

Comment: Is there some other way i can do it rather than using facebook login? Because i have to do the same for other social media's like instagram ,twitter etc. and right now i am doing posting to facebook from my application on behalf of the logged in user,who logs into my application with his email id.I think i saw somewhere ,adding user's fb handle to enable posting to fb on his behalf from a platform

Comment: No, there is no other way. For your app to be able to post on behalf of the user, the user needs to grant your app the necessary permission first - and that happens via the login dialog.